# How to form a string with "\" in it

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I am not able to form a string with "\" character using below method:

```
string strFullDomainName = "Domain"  + @"\" + "UserName";
```

I need to use this strFullDomainName to check against 
my SQLite table which has a field (string UserId) contain data for example: "Domain\User123"

```
var User = db.Query<Login>("Select * from Login Where UserId ='" + strFullDomainName  + "'");
```

How to solve this problem?

I use parameter query, the result is the same.

var User = db.Query("Select * from Location Where UserId =?", strFullDomainName );

Comment: Have you tried with a double backslash ? string strFullDomainName = "Domain"  + "\\" + "UserName";

Comment: Yes, I had tried using "\\" . The result is the same.

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting? If I were you, I'd be using parameters though. They save you the trouble and help prevent injection...

Comment: There is no error. It is just that there is no match. In SQLite table, the field UserId contain Example" "Domain\User1" and My strFullDomainName becomes like "Domain\\User1" There is an extra "\" when I use the above @"\" method.

Comment: I think you actually need to use four `\ `s. As in, `"\\\\"`. Basically it's "Add an 'escaped `\ `' using two 'escaped `\ `s'".

Comment: It is not working using "\\\\" or @"\\\\\" or @"\" or @"\\". Finally, I have to take the userId out from SQLite Table and break it up in two parts. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Path.Combine do this job!!!

```
string[] stringArray = {"Domain","UserName"};
var result = Path.Combine(stringArray);
```